# Only safe(?.)or non-null asserted(!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type MenuItem

Tags: android, kotlin

i am trying to add event for option menu items in android studio but i am getting this error message when i use item.itemId

> only safe(?.)or non-null asserted(!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable
>   receiver of type MenuItem

here is my code

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {

if(item.itemId==R.id.home){
    var homeIntent= Intent(this,SignIn::class.java)
    startActivity(homeIntent)

}
else if(item.itemId==R.id.sign_in){
    var signInIntent= Intent(this,SignIn::class.java)
    startActivity(signInIntent)

}
else if(item.itemId==R.id.close){
    System.exit(0)

}


return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Comment: `item` is of nullable type, so it can be null. In Kotlin, when you want to access something on a nullable type, you must use the safe operator `?.`, as the error message hints, in your case: `item?.itemId==R.id.home` etc.

Comment: @Melquiades many thanks for your reply this fix the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is `item` is defined as `nullable` . So you need to make sure that it should not be `null` before using it.

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    if(item?.itemId==R.id.home){
        var homeIntent= Intent(this,SignIn::class.java)
        startActivity(homeIntent)

    }
    else if(item?.itemId==R.id.sign_in){
        var signInIntent= Intent(this,SignIn::class.java)
        startActivity(signInIntent)

    }
    else if(item?.itemId==R.id.close){
        System.exit(0)

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Or you can use `let`

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
    item?.let {
        if(it.itemId==R.id.home){
            var homeIntent= Intent(this,SignIn::class.java)
            startActivity(homeIntent)

        }
        else if(it.itemId==R.id.sign_in){
            var signInIntent= Intent(this,SignIn::class.java)
            startActivity(signInIntent)

        }
        else if(it?.itemId==R.id.close){
            System.exit(0)

        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```