# Smart cast to 'Int' is impossible, because 'mViewModel.counter.value' is a complex expression

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is main activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mViewModel: MainActivityVm
    private lateinit var mTv: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

        mTv = findViewById(R.id.tv)

        mViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this)
                .get(MainActivityVm::class.java)

        mViewModel.counter.observe(this, Observer<Int> { counter ->
            mTv.setText(counter.toString())
        })

        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            if(null != mViewModel.counter.value)
            {
                mViewModel.counter.value++
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

I try to increment counter in data model when click on fab button

```
fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
    if(null != mViewModel.counter.value)
    {
        mViewModel.counter.value++
    }
}
```

but I gett error at line `mViewModel.counter.value++`

> Smart cast to 'Int' is impossible, because 'mViewModel.counter.value' is a complex expression

What does error mean?

Here is data model

```
class MainActivityVm : ViewModel() {
    val counter = MutableLiveData<Int>().apply { postValue(0)}
}
```

**edit**

If I comment out null check

```
fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
    //if(null != mViewModel.counter.value)
    //{
        mViewModel.counter.value++
    //}
}
```

I get error

> Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Int?

**edit**

using null check with `!!`

```
    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        if(null != mViewModel.counter.value)
        {
            mViewModel.counter!!.value++
        }
    }
```

gives initial error

> Smart cast to 'Int' is impossible, because 'mViewModel.counter.value' is a complex expression

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315107/only-safe-or-non-null-asserted-calls-are-allowed-on-a-nullable-receiver

Comment: Have you try this `mViewModel.counter?.value++`

Comment: @Leo yeah, then i get `Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type Int?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the [MutableLiveData#postValue()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData.html#postValue(T)) method.

Also, it's better to put the functionality inside the ViewModel.

Add a method in the ViewModel to increment the counter:

```
class MainActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val counter = MutableLiveData<Int>().apply { postValue(0)}

    public fun incrementCounter() {
        counter.let {
            val currentVal: Int? = it.value
            currentVal?.let { cur ->
                it.postValue(cur + 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This can also be written as:

```
public fun incrementCounter() {
    val currentVal: Int? = counter.value
    if (currentVal != null)
        counter.postValue(currentVal + 1)
}
```

Then, just call that method when the FAB is clicked:

```
    fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
        viewModel.incrementCounter()
    }
```

Comment: So old fashion null check is not thread safe but `value?.let ` is?

Comment: @the_prole That's just how I wrote it the kotlin way, but on second look it's actually even shorter with a null check, so I added that alternate implementation to the answer.  The main issue is just to use `postValue()` instead of using `++`.

Comment: Oh, I thought I had to use `.let` to create a local copy of `value` to protect against another thread changing `value` to null just after the null check, or Kotlin wouldn't compile. Guess not.